# Understanding virtual environment behavior

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a virtual environment and install an older version of pandas. I'm working with anaconda and conda create to make the new environment. I've successfully created an environment with base python, installed pandas 0.13.1, but when I activate my environment and check `pandas.__version__` it's telling me it imported the pandas version from my regular development environment (anaconda), pandas 0.14.0.

I've included a screenshot of the install process taking place within the environment, env. I've redacted the env name and username as my company is less than thrilled with back-end 3rd party installs...

The little screen section is the `version.py` from the pandas folder inside the env environment

Even checking `where python` shows the env is the first interpreter listed:

[image: Screenshot of installation details]

Set `PYTHONPATH` for regular and virtual env:
[image: set PYTHONPATH]

Trying to use conda for the virtual environment creation as anaconda is tailored to its use instead of virtualenv.

Comment: What does `set PYTHONPATH` say?

Comment: @WolfgangUlmer I put it in the question. I would have assumed it would change when activating env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `PYTHONPATH` when using Anaconda. Virtual environments conflict with `PYTHONPATH` so make sure that you only have Python package directories in your `PYTHONPATH` which are *not* managed by Anaconda.

In your case, `PYTHONPATH` should be `C:\UtilityCode;C:\PycharmProjects`.